# Codeigniter Dynamic Subdomain to a function

Tags: codeigniter, subdomain

I need to dynamic subdomain *.mysite.com to codeigniter function.
(config to hosting has done)

if I enter sub.mysite.com to www.mysite.com/index.php/en/web/sub/

if I enter sub.mysite.com/parameter need to www.mysite.com/index.php/en/web/sub/parameter

Please help me codeigniter experts and .htaccess experts..

Answer (score 0):

Remove the your Index.php File

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /sub/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

create the subdomain in your cpanel[image]

Comment: hi kuldeep.. THanks for the reply. But my requirement is I jst want to use given any sub domain (dynamic) as a parameter to a controller method.

Comment: as follows -- www.subdomain.mysite.com/home  --> www.mysite.com/index.php/en/site/home